# Two models: discrepancy between AIC values and fit plots. Which one to choose?

Tags: regression, survival

Which model should be preferred if one (m1) has better AIC and another (m2) better fit plot?

**Model 1 (m1): includes "sex"**

```
flexsurvreg(Surv(time, status) ~ group + sex + age + comorbidity, dist="weibull", data = data)
```

Log-likelihood = -15802.47

AIC = 31616.93

**Model 2 (m2): does not include "sex"**

```
flexsurvreg(Surv(time, status) ~ group + age + comorbidity, dist="weibull", data = data)
```

Log-likelihood = -15875.16

AIC = 31760.32

**Fit plot: KM curves, m1 and m2 prediction for two study groups**
[image]

NB! Stratified analysis by "sex" would not be a good solution as one group is quite small (n = 50).

NB2! The estimates of the predictor we are interested in, are very similar between two models (0.81 vs 0.83). This also applies for the other predictors and CIs.

**ADDED AFTER COMMENTS:**

Maybe this is due to an error in coding "newdata" argument: group A is combined with females only and vice versa.

[image]

Code I used for "newdata" argument:

```
summary(m1, newdata=data.frame(group=c("A", "B"), age = 50, sex = c("f","m"), comorbidity = 2), type = "survival", ci = TRUE, tidy = T)
```

Is there a way to get such summary table for group A and B in a way that both, females and males, are included?

Comment: Could you articulate the sense in which you find the plot for m2 "better" than the plot for m1?

Comment: Thank you! As much as I understand, the KM and prediction curves should converge (be close to each other). If so, the fit is considered to be good? Also, I worked more with this package and found out that maybe this is due to an error in "newdata" argument (please see the added part of the initial post).